# Angular bootstrap ui issue with online website

Tags: angularjs, bower

i'm developing a website which has a fully Angular front-end.It works well in my local server.When i moved the site to an online one, it gives an bower related error.I was used angular bootstrap ui cdn.But for other Angular related files are loading through a bower.json file.So i'm confused why this error occurs.Hope someone help me to solve this.

Comment: What is the exact error you get? Also, is this site in a public URL?

Comment: I'm getting this error in the console:angular.js:13236 Error: [$injector:unpr] http://errors.angularjs.org/1.5.0/$injector/unpr?p0=%24modalProvider%20%3C-%20%24modal%20%3C-%20AngularController

Comment: The problem seems to be that 'AngularController' is not getting injected properly, this most likely has to do with the paths set for the js file containing the said controller.

Comment: Thanks for the reply.But the problem is same codebase works well in the localhost.

Comment: Yes, the problem could be 
1. The URLs are given as absolute paths 
2. URLs given in a path that works in your local machine but not the server(OS differences etc)
3. All resources not being uploaded to the server 

If you can share the html file where the js files are added.

Comment: Yes, i can understand your point.But i have given all the paths as relative paths.And have uploaded all the resources to the server.